# How to generalize CSV-JSON conversion associating array elements (attribute names) with CSV lines by index using jq?

Tags: bash, jq

My question is really simple but I am new to `jq`. All I want is to associate array elements (my attributes) and csv lines (my data) by index:

```
"arr[0]":"csv[0]"
"arr[1]":"csv[1]"
...
"arr[n-1]":"csv[n-1]"
```

I know how to do it manually but I want some generalizing code.

My code is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="$1"
OUTPUT="$2"
ATTRIB_NAMES=("name" "code" "email")
MAIN_NAME="students"

jq --arg jq_var ${ATTRIB_NAMES} --arg jq_var ${MAIN_NAME} -Rsn '
    {"'${MAIN_NAME}'":
        [inputs
        | . / "\n"
        | (.[] | select(length > 0) | . / ";") as $input
        | {
            "'${ATTRIB_NAMES[0]}'": $input[0],
            "'${ATTRIB_NAMES[1]}'": $input[1],
            "'${ATTRIB_NAMES[2]}'": $input[2]
          }
        ]
   }
' < $INPUT
```

`$INPUT` is the CSV file, like `data.csv`. In my case this file have lines like:

```
x;y;z
a;b;c
```

`$OUTPUT` is the name of output file, like `final.json`. In this file I am getting something like this:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "code": "y",
      "email": "z"
    },
    {
      "name": "a",
      "code": "b",
      "email": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to use something like `"'${ATTRIB_NAMES[i]}'": $input[i]` to get the same result I am getting. The advantage is I can use this script in many different CSV files just reseting `ATTRIB_NAMES` array.

Any other recommendation will be welcome :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  What, for example, would an example of $INPUT be?  Also, please note that one cannot import a bash array in the way your code attempts to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn an input like

```
x;y;z
a;b;c
```

into an output like

```json
{
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "code": "y",
      "email": "z"
    },
    {
      "name": "a",
      "code": "b",
      "email": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

given the field names `"name"`, `"code"`, and `"email"`, you could provide the field names as positional arguments using `--args`, split the linewise `inputs` at `";"` using `/`, and match keys and values using `with_entries`:

```bash
< data.csv jq -Rn '{
  students: [(inputs / ";") | with_entries(.key |= $ARGS.positional[.])]
}' --args name code email   # or --args "${ATTRIB_NAMES[@]}"
```

This works for inputs in the format given, but not for every possible CSV, because it expects `";"` as column separator, and doesn't recognize any special value escapes (please add them to your sample input if you want them considered).

---

Update #1: The solution above uses `--args`, and therefore requires jq 1.6+. For a jq 1.5 solution, you could turn the list of field names into a JSON array (either manually or by using another jq filter), and then read it into a variable using `--argjson`. The latter is effectively the same as just concatenating the field names by a character that doesn't occur within the names themselves (e.g. newline or space), then reading it into a string variable using `--arg`, and splitting it back into an array inside jq:

```bash
< data.csv jq -Rn '{
  students: [(inputs / ";") | with_entries(.key |= $names[.])]
}' --argjson names '["name", "code", "email"]'   # or
#  --argjson names "$(printf '%s\n' "${ATTRIB_NAMES[@]}" | jq -Rn '[inputs]')"

# or

< data.csv jq -Rn '{
  students: [(inputs / ";") | with_entries(.key |= ($names / " ")[.])]
}' --arg names 'name code email'   # or --arg names "${ATTRIB_NAMES[*]}"
```

---

Update #2:
If you also want the superordinate key (here `"students"`) to be dynamic, just add it the same way using `--arg`. Works with all versions discussed above:

```bash
< data.csv jq -Rn --arg name "students" '{
  ($name): [(inputs / ";") …
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. This code didn't work for me as `jq` doesn't recognize `args` parameter (`arg` only). I am getting `jq: Unknown option --args`. I am using `jq-1.5-1`.

Comment: @eightShirt Yes, `--args` was introduced with jq 1.6 (in 2018! - consider updating your software). If this is the version you have (or want) to stick to, I've added some work-arounds that should be compatible with jq 1.5

Comment: it works! Thank you @pmf! As I suspected, it was something quite simple :)